# How to print only the created columns in Sharepoint using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I need to print only the column that has been created by me.

```
function retrieveFieldsOfListView(listTitle,viewName){

   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var listFields = list.get_fields();
   context.load(listFields);
   context.executeQueryAsync(printFieldNames,onError);


   function printFieldNames() {
      var e = listFields.getEnumerator();
      while (e.moveNext()) {
         var fieldName = e.get_title();
         console.log(fieldName);
      }
   }

   function onError(sender,args)
   {
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }

    }
```

But this code is printing all the pre-defined fields along with my field. I don't want the pre-defined fields like 'modified,created,etc'. I want only the coding changes. UI changes are not upto me.

Comment: How do you plan to separate your own fields from the default fields?

Comment: I don't know how to separate. I've just created my fields using UI.

Answer (score 1):

### How to determine whether field is *system* or *user-defined*

Probably the most reliable way to determine whether field is *system* or *user-defined* is to utilize `SourceId` property of a Field. For system fields it's value is set to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3`

Note: [SP.Field object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246815.aspx) does **not** expose `SourceId` property, but it could be extracted from  [SP.Field.schemaXml property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244913.aspx) as demonstrated below:

```
function getListFields(listTitle,success,error){

   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var fields = list.get_fields();
   context.load(fields);
   context.executeQueryAsync(
      function(){
          success(fields);
      },
      error);
}




//Usage
getListFields('Pages',
   function(fields) {
      //get only user defined fields
      var userDefinedFields = fields.get_data().filter(function(f){
          var schema = f.get_schemaXml();
          if (schema.indexOf('SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"') === -1){
              return f;
          }
      });

      //print user defined fields title
      userDefinedFields.forEach(function(f){
          console.log(f.get_title()); 
      });
   },
   function(sender,args)
   {
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

---

Like a said `SourceId` property is not available for Field object, the below example demonstrates a different approach for getting field properties

```
function getListFields(listTitle,success,error){

   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var fields = list.get_fields();
   context.load(fields,'Include(SchemaXml)');
   context.executeQueryAsync(
      function(){
          var result = [];
          fields.get_data().forEach(function(f){
             var schema = f.get_schemaXml(); 
             result.push(schemaXml2Json(schema));
          });    
          success(result);
      },
      error);
}


function schemaXml2Json(schemaXml)
{ 
    var jsonObject = {};
    var schemaXmlDoc = $.parseXML(schemaXml);
    $(schemaXmlDoc).find('Field').each(function() {
      $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attr){
           jsonObject[attr.name] = attr.value;
      });
    });
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Then you could use `SourceId` property:

```
getListFields('Pages',
   function(fields) {
      //get only user defined fields
      var userDefinedFields = fields.filter(function(f){
          if (f.SourceID !== "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"){
              return f;
          }
      });

      //print user defined fields title
      userDefinedFields.forEach(function(f){
          console.log(f.DisplayName); 
      });
   },
   function(sender,args)
   {
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```